# Virtual KVM (Software KVM)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, kvm-switch

We have the popular Synergy and Input Director software KM solutions, where you can share a mouse and keyboard over network with another computer.

However i would also like to share video (Monitor) over network.

Is there any **cross platform, software** product that offers full KVM functionality over network?

Comment: Perhaps something like VNC?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. I'd like to very literally have my screen switch and display the contents of another computer (that is, i do not want to open a window and access the other computer through said window.)

If i were using a Linux host computer, this would probably be doable via the console switching function, but the problem with that would still be that i will be using a windows host)

Comment: @Cestarian you ever solve this problem? I'm in the exact same scenario - looking to repurpose my workstation as a hypervisor / compute node and possibly use some kind of DaaS / thin client solution, but haven't yet solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late follow up...

I've found my solution. My monitor (and most monitors I think) comes with a few input ports, one dvi and one vga in my case. And my monitor (also most monitors I think) happens to have built-in switching capability, that is to say when the monitor does not detect any input, it checks all the ports to see if the monitor is connected to anything.

Since both windows and linux have the capability to turn off the display to save power (screen blank essentially) if I blank one and make sure the other is unblanked, the screen will always show me whichever system is unblanked.

Basically what I do then is just use synergy to switch between the displays (I'm using a hardware USB switch right now, but I used synergy before, and honestly I think it was just better than this..., but since I have a gaming keyboard this allows me to have per-system keyboard configs, and also allows me to switch hids like a drawing tablet if needed) and I have keybound on my synergy host (this would usually be Linux) to switch the keyboard and mouse in synergy over to the windows machine, and then blank the screen, then unblank the one on windows.

Then to switch back I do the reverse, it took a little scripting (xdotool and xbindkeys... and on windows I use autohotkey) but it works pretty well.

The major issue I'm running into is sound, this answer is good enough since I didn't specifically ask for sound, only good solutions I found was linking the line-out from one machine to the line-in of the one using the speakers and then mixing the sound to output that, but the drawback there is that there will be some added noise and the volume will be noticably reduced. The only other way I found was setting up Mumble as a sound server, it was really high quality and really nice, stable low latency... but as things stand it only supports mono sound as input.

Streaming sound from linux to linux is easy, windows to windows is easy, but linux to windows or the other way around, that stuff is kinda hard...

However there's the solution for the video streaming issue, most monitors will have built in video switching capability if you just via software blank the screens selectively to switch :)

We know it's possible to do this well via software (Steam In-Home Streaming proved this) but I don't see any ready and willing software out there for this specific purpose, which makes me kinda sad. All the other solutions I've seen are too high latency or too low quality (usually both).

Answer (score 1):

[VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) Is a great option if you need to remote control a machine or, in your case, let someone else see your screen. It has limitations and is not as fancy as other solutions but it is free and cross platform!

VNC will not work outside a LAN environment unless you forward ports or use a VPN solution.

There are also many flavors of VNC (this is why i linked the wikipedia site as it lists them all). I personally prefer RealVNC.

Some other options that, depending on the environment and how you plan to use them, may or may not be free:

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) is another great option (and one that will work inside and outside of your network). It is what I use to help family and friends remotely since the initial setup is so easy!

[ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/) is an option I have looked at before but chose not to use because of its cost. They have some pretty sweet options but it is not the type of solution I was looking for. If you need to rebrand your tool they can make it look pretty sweet.

Keep in mind the limitations of all of these pieces of software for remote viewing and support:

Latency and image quality are dependant on both your connection and the speed of the remote machine.

They are pretty much all terrible for video right now unless you have the resources (bandwidth and CPU).

Security! VNC can be configured to use encryption but is not always the standard. You also have to consider how good your passwords are (especially if you enable access from outside your network!)

Comment: Wrote this up before the comments on the main thread popped up. There are no tools to let you switch, as you describe, without using an app or another window. Do keep in mind that full screen support is an option and, to the un-initiated, makes it look like your sitting at the remote computer.

Comment: The problem with running it full screen from a window is usually that there are problems that follow it, such as tool/taskbars for the program itself that are unrelated to what i'm doing in my guest computer. It needs to feel like i'm just switching my screen, keyboard and mouse between two computers even if i'm just opening a fullscreen program (sort of like alt-tabbing in and out of a video game)

Comment: VNC supports hiding all those buttons. For your Windows based computers, running the right version of windows at least and only between two Windows computers, you can use the built in Remote Desktop tool. I wish it worked for non Windows machines... 

It does take a little effort to accomplish what you want but the tools and configurations of those tools exist to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew M has pointed out a good list of software solutions.  Judging from the comments there, you seem a bit dissatisfied.  Nothing in software is ever going to be as good as a real KVM, and it's a limitation that you just have to deal with.  Here's why:

1. Latency.
2. Graphics acceleration options on your host system don't translate across a remote desktop solution.  High end games and other software using this kind of feature won't work well remotely.
3. Bit depth.  The higher the bit depth, the more bandwidth will be consumed by screen updates.  Each software solution has a different approach to pushing screen updates to the client end.  Some will deliver a near exact mirror, and some will go "fuzzy" for the sake of saving bandwidth.  Some will let you decide on how much bandwidth you want to consume.
4. Keyboard options.  Hardware KVMS let you do things like "tap, tap" on the scroll lock or similar to switch between displays -- but they are wired to intercept these commands from the keyboard BEFORE they are transmitted to the host.  Software can't do this as well so some things you do on a keyboard *need* to have custom hooks for you to invoke them; sometimes on-screen, or sometimes through 'alternate' key combinations.

Comment: I have a problem with using a real KVM, i have a utility(gaming) keyboard which requires more power than the KVM is willing to output to the keyboard. I'd need a non-emulated USB port on the KVM switch for it to work, ports designed for external hard drives and printers or such devices, and the problem with finding that is that the descriptions of the switch usually won't say. Meaning i'd have to blindly buy switches until i'd get one that works.